# Trying to find a specified object in JSON and then print all of the different objects in the same embed. DIscord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Basically I'm trying to make a bot that sends a specified item's features into the chat when an user searched for it.

The thing is when I do **!search Animal Skull** nothing happens but It should show Animal Skull's features like Name and ID.

code

```
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js"); 
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
datapath = path.resolve('data.json')


module.exports = {
  config: {
    name: "search",
    description: "Search for items!",
  },
  permissions: ['SendMessages'],
  owner: false,
  run: async (client, message, args, prefix, config, db) => {
    fs.readFile(datapath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
          throw err;
      }

      const jsondata = JSON.parse(data.toString());
      var needle = args;
      for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++){
        if (jsondata[i].names == needle){
      message.reply({ embeds: [
        new EmbedBuilder()
          .setTitle(jsondata[i].names)
          .setThumbnail(jsondata[i].image)
          .setDescription(`Item type: **${jsondata[i].itemtype}**\n Item ID: **${jsondata[i].itemid}**\n Rarity: **${jsondata[i].itemrarity}**\n Farmable: **${jsondata[i].itemfarmable}**\n Droppable: **${jsondata[i].itemdroppable}**`)
          .setColor("Green")
      ] })
    }}
    })
  },
};
```

json

```
[
    {
        "names": "Animal Skull",
        "itemtype": "Block",
        "itemid": "32",
        "itemrarity": "4",
        "itemfarmable": "No",
        "itemdroppable": "Yes",
        "image": "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/cubixworlds/images/4/4c/Animal_Skull.png/revision/latest?cb=20220720212850"
    },
    {
        "names": "Asteroid Block",
        "itemtype": "Block",
        "itemid": "1",
        "itemrarity": "1",
        "itemfarmable": "No",
        "itemdroppable": "Yes",
        "image": "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/cubixworlds/images/f/fe/Asteroid_Block.png/revision/latest?cb=20220725063800"
    },
    {
        "names": "Bathtub",
        "itemtype": "Block",
        "itemid": "129",
        "itemrarity": "8",
        "itemfarmable": "No",
        "itemdroppable": "Yes",
        "image": "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/cubixworlds/images/5/5a/Bathtub.png/revision/latest?cb=20220722112339"
    }
]
```

I would be so gratefull if anyone can help.

Comment: I'd console log `args` variable first. I just have a feeling that `args` is an array of strings, but have no way to reproduce and check.

Comment: Hmm it came out like this ```[ 'Animal', 'Skull' ]```

Comment: `['Animal', 'Skull'].join(" ");` => `'Animal Skull'`. I guess the issue is now resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the .forEach function instead of a for loop!

Try this:

```
      jsondata.forEach(thing => {
        if (thing.names.toLowerCase() != needle.toLowerCase()) return;

      message.reply({ embeds: [
        new EmbedBuilder()
          .setTitle(thing.names)
          .setThumbnail(thing.image)
          .setDescription(`Use the thing variable instead the jsondata[i]`)
          .setColor("Green")
      ] })
    }
```

Also I added a .toLowerCase() so no more problems with cases :)

Hope this helps ;)